# Archive log backup error and backup completed with errors

Tags: oracle, rman, backup

My prod DB backup completed with errors stating the below error.

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ch01 channel at 05/08/2014 09:24:07
ORA-19588: archived log recid 161391 stamp 907826104 is no longer valid
```

What to do?

Comment: Does it exist on disk? Have you done a RESETLOGS or anything else odd?

Comment: No. it exists on tape and daily backup script runs but today it completed with error. any solution?

Comment: This mostly happens when more than one RMAN session runs at the same time (in the same database of course). If I were you, I would review the backup schedule and logs, check the possibility of overlapping backups (e.g. full backup and archivelog backup running at same time). The V$RMAN_OUTPUT view may also contain some useful insight on this case.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when one processes cleans the archives and an other finds the need to backup it. Things to check:

1. do you have a archive log clean script other than rman? (hope not)
2. do you run archive log backups during the full database backup? if so, don't make archive backups in the db backup script but only in the archivelog backup script.